# How is it that torch is not installed by torchvision?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

Somehow when I do the install it installs `torchvision` but not `torch`. Command I am running as dictated from the main website:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

then I do conda list but look:

```
$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36h306e16b_0
anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36h44fb852_0
argparse                  1.4.0                     <pip>
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astroid                   1.6.3                    py36_0
astropy                   3.0.2            py36h3010b51_1
attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0
autovizwidget             0.12.7                    <pip>
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0
backports                 1.0              py36hfa02d7e_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36hfea85ff_2
bcrypt                    3.1.6                     <pip>
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36h49b8c8c_1
bitarray                  0.8.1            py36h14c3975_1
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h735825a_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h4e06776_0
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0
blosc                     1.14.3               hdbcaa40_0
bokeh                     1.0.4                    py36_0
boto                      2.48.0           py36h6e4cd66_1
boto3                     1.9.146                   <pip>
boto3                     1.9.134                    py_0
botocore                  1.12.146                  <pip>
botocore                  1.12.134                   py_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36haac1ea0_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0
cached-property           1.5.1                     <pip>
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py36_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h9745a5d_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h0f667ec_1
click                     6.7              py36h5253387_0
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py36h7e57e65_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h489cec4_0
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36h6c84a62_0
cryptography              2.3.1            py36hc365091_0
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
curl                      7.60.0               h84994c4_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h93f1223_0
cymem                     2.0.2            py36hfd86e86_0
cython                    0.28.2           py36h14c3975_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h14c3975_0
dask                      0.17.5                   py36_0
dask-core                 0.17.5                   py36_0
dataclasses               0.6                        py_0    fastai
datashape                 0.5.4            py36h3ad6b5c_0
dbus                      1.13.2               h714fa37_1
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
dill                      0.2.9                    py36_0
distributed               1.21.8                   py36_0
docker                    3.7.2                     <pip>
docker-compose            1.24.0                    <pip>
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                     <pip>
dockerpty                 0.4.1                     <pip>
docopt                    0.6.2                     <pip>
docutils                  0.14             py36hb0f60f5_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36h1aec115_2
environment-kernels       1.1.1                     <pip>
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36hd6bccc3_0
expat                     2.2.5                he0dffb1_0
fastai                    1.0.52                        1    fastai
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h14c3975_2
fastprogress              0.1.21                     py_0    fastai
filelock                  3.0.4                    py36_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1
flask-cors                3.0.4                    py36_0
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0
gevent                    1.3.0            py36h14c3975_0
glib                      2.56.1               h000015b_0
glob2                     0.6              py36he249c77_0
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36hc8893dd_2
graphite2                 1.3.11               h16798f4_2
graphviz                  2.40.1               h21bd128_2
greenlet                  0.4.13           py36h14c3975_0
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1
h5py                      2.8.0            py36h989c5e5_3
harfbuzz                  1.8.4                hec2c2bc_0
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1
hdijupyterutils           0.12.7                    <pip>
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h2f9c1c0_0
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1
idna                      2.6              py36h82fb2a8_1
imageio                   2.3.0                    py36_0
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0
ipyparallel               6.2.2                     <pip>
ipython                   6.4.0                    py36_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36hb52b0d5_0
ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py36_0
ipywidgets                7.4.0                     <pip>
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0
itsdangerous              0.24             py36h93cc618_1
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0
jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_1
jinja2                    2.10             py36ha16c418_0
jmespath                  0.9.4                      py_0
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h006f8b5_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36he59e554_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h7c827e3_0
jupyterlab                0.32.1                   py36_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.5                   py36_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h764f252_0
krb5                      1.14.2               hcdc1b81_6
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h10fcdad_0
libcurl                   7.60.0               h1ad7b7a_0
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libprotobuf               3.5.2                hd28b015_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                h9cfc8f7_4
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_1
libtool                   2.4.6                h544aabb_3
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1
libxml2                   2.9.8                h26e45fe_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0
llvmlite                  0.23.1           py36hdbcaa40_0
locket                    0.2.0            py36h787c0ad_1
lxml                      4.2.1            py36h23eabaa_0
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2
markupsafe                1.0              py36hd9260cd_1
matplotlib                2.2.2                     <pip>
matplotlib                3.0.3            py36h5429711_0
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36h5ad9710_1
mistune                   0.8.3            py36h14c3975_1
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h17a0993_4
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py36h7dd41cf_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h629b387_0
mock                      3.0.5                     <pip>
more-itertools            4.1.0                    py36_0
mpc                       1.0.3                hec55b23_5
mpfr                      3.1.5                h11a74b3_2
mpi                       1.0                     openmpi    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hfeacd6b_2
msgpack                   0.6.0                     <pip>
msgpack-numpy             0.4.3.2                  py36_0
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36h6bb024c_0
multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py36_0
murmurhash                1.0.2            py36he6710b0_0
nb_conda                  2.2.1                    py36_2    conda-forge
nb_conda_kernels          2.2.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.4.1                    py36_3
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h31c9010_0
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0
ninja                     1.8.2            py36h6bb024c_1
nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0
nose                      1.3.7            py36hcdf7029_2
notebook                  5.5.0                    py36_0
numba                     0.38.0           py36h637b7d7_0
numexpr                   2.6.5            py36h7bf3b9c_0
numpy                     1.15.4           py36h1d66e8a_0
numpy                     1.15.4                    <pip>
numpy-base                1.15.4           py36h81de0dd_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
nvidia-ml-py3             7.352.0                    py_0    fastai
odo                       0.5.1            py36h90ed295_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0
onnx                      1.4.1                     <pip>
openmpi                   3.1.0                h26a2512_3    conda-forge
openpyxl                  2.5.3                    py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2r               h7b6447c_0
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0
pandas                    0.24.2                    <pip>
pandas                    0.23.0           py36h637b7d7_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36ha6701b7_1
pango                     1.42.3               h8589676_0
paramiko                  2.4.2                     <pip>
parso                     0.2.0                    py36_0
partd                     0.3.8            py36h36fd896_0
patchelf                  0.9                  hf79760b_2
path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_0
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0
pcre                      8.42                 h439df22_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
pexpect                   4.5.0                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h63277f8_0
pillow                    5.2.0            py36heded4f4_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0
pixman                    0.34.0               hceecf20_3
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1
plac                      0.9.6                    py36_0
plotly                    2.7.0                     <pip>
pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hb689045_0
ply                       3.11                     py36_0
preshed                   2.0.1            py36he6710b0_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h17d85b1_0
protobuf                  3.5.2            py36hd28b015_0    conda-forge
protobuf3-to-dict         0.1.5                     <pip>
psutil                    5.4.5            py36h14c3975_0
psycopg2                  2.7.5                     <pip>
ptyprocess                0.5.2            py36h69acd42_0
py                        1.5.3                    py36_0
py4j                      0.10.7                    <pip>
pyasn1                    0.4.5                     <pip>
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h0a5515d_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hf9f622e_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h14c3975_8
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36hb7f436b_0
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36h7bd6a15_0
pygal                     2.4.0                     <pip>
pygments                  2.2.0            py36h0d3125c_0
pykerberos                1.2.1            py36h14c3975_0
pylint                    1.8.4                    py36_0
PyNaCl                    1.3.0                     <pip>
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36hf484d3e_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36hee85983_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h751905a_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0
pyspark                   2.3.2                     <pip>
pytables                  3.4.3            py36h02b9ad4_2
pytest                    3.5.1                    py36_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.2                      py36_0
pytest-astropy            0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-remotedata         0.2.1                    py36_0
python                    3.6.5                hc3d631a_2
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0
pytorch                   1.1.0           py3.6_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0    pytorch
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36he602eb0_0
pyyaml                    3.12             py36hafb9ca4_1
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36h14c3975_0
qt                        5.9.6                h52aff34_0
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h609ed8c_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h8f73b5b_0
qtpy                      1.4.1                    py36_0
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4
regex                     2018.01.10      py36h14c3975_1000    fastai
requests                  2.20.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
requests-kerberos         0.12.0                    <pip>
rope                      0.10.7           py36h147e2ec_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36h14c3975_1
s3fs                      0.1.5                    py36_0
s3transfer                0.2.0                     <pip>
s3transfer                0.2.0                    py36_0
sagemaker                 1.20.1                    <pip>
sagemaker-pyspark         1.2.4                     <pip>
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36h14c3975_1
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h7aa7ec6_0
scikit-learn              0.20.3                    <pip>
scipy                     1.1.0            py36hfc37229_0
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36hfad7ec4_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                39.1.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h7a266c3_0
sip                       4.19.8           py36hf484d3e_0
six                       1.11.0           py36h372c433_1
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h6febd40_0
sortedcollections         0.6.1                    py36_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.10                   py36_0
spacy                     2.0.18          py36hf484d3e_1000    fastai
sparkmagic                0.12.5                    <pip>
sphinx                    1.7.4                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36h6d0f590_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36hb5cb234_1
spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0
SQLAlchemy                1.2.11                    <pip>
sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py36h6b74fdf_0
sqlite                    3.23.1               he433501_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h3010b51_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py36hc6d1c1c_0
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h34cf8b6_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h8cadb63_0
texttable                 0.9.1                     <pip>
thinc                     6.12.1          py36h637b7d7_1000    fastai
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0
torchvision               0.2.2                      py_3    pytorch
tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0
tqdm                      4.31.1                   py36_1
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h674d592_0
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0
typing-extensions         3.7.2                     <pip>
ujson                     1.35             py36h14c3975_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36ha668878_0
unixodbc                  2.3.6                h1bed415_0
urllib3                   1.23                     py36_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36hdf4376a_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h800622e_1
websocket-client          0.56.0                    <pip>
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                     <pip>
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36h28b7045_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h1db9f0c_1
xlsxwriter                1.0.4                    py36_0
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h7b00a1f_0
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                h439df22_0
zict                      0.1.3            py36h3a3bf81_0
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2
```

I was told I do have pytorch installed but my script keeps giving me this error:

```
$ cat nohup.out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "high_performing_data_point_models_cifar10.py", line 5, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

does that mean that I need to install it as pytroch and not torch? Is this not weird?

---

Note I am running this on an AWS instance `p3.2xlarge`. This keeps happening when I log out and then go back in that my torch package gets missing...?!?! :/

---

original post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torchvision-installed-but-not-torch/51758

---

The issue persists even if I open just a python interactive and try to import it:

```
(pytorch_p36) ubuntu@ip-123-12-21-123:~$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>>
```

It also happens running the script directly:

```
(pytorch_p36) ubuntu@ip-123-12-21-123:~/project/folder$ python high_performing_data_point_models_cifar10.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "high_performing_data_point_models_cifar10.py", line 5, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

---

I can't import torchvision either!

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torchvision
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision'
>>>
```

Comment: Are you using the python executable to which you added the conda packages? What does `which python` output?

Comment: Hmm... That's weird. Maybe it's `conda` issue, try to `conda update conda` and then repeat the installation.

Comment: Are you sure that you are activating the conda environment before executing the scripts?

Comment: Also, are you executing your script through ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Your `conda list` command shows that it was run from the environment called `automl`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/automl:
```

However, when you show the commands that you are trying to run, you are doing so from the `(pytorch_p36)` environment.

You should run your `conda install` command while inside this `pytorch_p36` environment.

Comment: I have no idea why it said that...I've corrected the output of conda list...all the errors remain the same... :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to the official website and try installing it as said over there. As I just followed the official documentation and it is working fine.
Here is the step though.

conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
You can follow the official documentation.

[link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#anaconda)

Comment: what makes you think I am not following the official instructions from the website?

Comment: See I followed the official documentation and tried executing the example given over there and its working fine so maybe you are missing something or there is something wrong with the installation. Better if you can create the new environment and test it again with the sample example or any example of your choice.@CharlieParker

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to miss smth while working with several machines and several conda/python environments. I think it is a good idea to start from the very beginning. Here is installation process that works fine for me.

### 0. Connect to your `aws-instance` using SSH or PuTTY.

### 1. Create conda env named `pytorch_p36` with `python 3.6` on your aws machine:

```
user@aws-instance:~$ conda create -n pytorch_p36 python=3.6
```

### 2. Activate it:

```
user@aws-instance:~$ conda activate pytorch_p36
```

Or with (for older `conda` versions):

```
user@aws-instance:~$ source activate pytorch_p36
```

Now you should see `(pytorch_p36)` before your shell prompt:

```
(pytorch_p36) user@aws-instance:~$
```

### 3. Go to [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/) and choose appropriate installation command via `conda`. Run it in your shell:

```
(pytorch_p36) user@aws-instance:~$ conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

### 4. Verify the installation:

```
(pytorch_p36) user@aws-instance:~$ conda list

# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...    
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
... 
python                    3.6.9                h265db76_0
pytorch                   1.1.0           py3.6_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0    pytorch
...
torchvision               0.3.0           py36_cu10.0.130_1    pytorch
...
```

### 5. Verify the running with `nohup`:

```
(pytorch_p36) user@aws-instance:~$ nohup python -c "import torch; import torchvision; print('PyTorch is fine!')" && cat nohup.out
```

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
PyTorch is fine!
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Machine Learning AMI already has `pytorch` v1.1.0 and `torchvision` v0.2.2 installed in the predefined `pytorch_p36` virtual environment. So you are not required to create new venv and install `pytorch` each time you log in. All you need is to run :

```
$ source activate pytorch_p36
```

(without dollar sign, obviously). Then, if you run `pip show torch` you will see that it is already there.